# How to restore own nuget package in another solution

Tags: c#, nuget, visual-studio-2017

I have **C# solution** called `commons` where I have my Model and some common stuff that will be used by other solutions.

As a Post Build Event I create a **nuget** package and copy it to my local **Nuget** `folder ("C:\packages")`

**Post Build Event:**

`"$(ProjectDir)nuget.exe" pack "$(ProjectDir)Commons.csproj" -
IncludeReferencedProjects`

`xcopy Commons.1.0.0.nupkg c:\packages /Y`

> **Note**: Version never changes.

That creates successfully my new nuget package.

Then on the other solution I reference that package and I can see everything ok.
I can access all my models and everything.

**The problem I have is**

if I make any change to my Common projects *(e.g add a new field to my model)* this will not appear on my solution.

What am I missing??

Comment: did you uninstall/reinstall package? or maybe should change the version # and update it in the other solution.

Comment: Yes, used `Update-Package Commons -reinstall`

Answer (score 0):

- Create package with higher version than previous
- Copy the new package to a Shared Folder
- Make sure the folder has following structure

  `packageName/version/[packageName].[version].nupkg
  v1: abc.common/1.0.0/abc.common.1.0.0.nupkg
  v2: abc.common/2.0.0/abc.common.2.0.0.nupkg`
- Make sure the newer package has higher version, not just on the folder structure but also the nuspec file. You can rename .nupkg to zip file, and access the nuspec file. Or use package explorer https://github.com/NuGetPackageExplorer/NuGetPackageExplorer
- Now add package to the shared folder eg: \\localhost\mypackages and use this shared url as a package source in visual studio

VS will automatically show upgrade button if there new version published.

Comment: Thanks, could you guide me on how to do that via command line?

Answer (score 0):

> if I make any change to my Common projects (e.g add a new field to my model) this will not appear on my solution.

Long story.

To resolve this issue, you should make sure two points, **re-pack the package** and **re-install the re-packed to the solution** after change your `Commons` project.

**1. Re-pack the package:**

After make some change to the `Commons` projects, you should re-pack the nuget package. For your situation, you should rebuild the `Commons` project to generate the new nuget package.

Besides, whether you need to change the version number depends on your own requirement, we recommend to change the version number before you want to publish a new nuget package.

To accomplish this, modify the `AssemblyVersion` in the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file before you publish the new version nuget package. For example,

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.1")]
```

After build, you will get the nuget package `Commons.1.0.0.1.nupkg` in the `bin` folder, you can use wildcard `*` in your copy command to copy package to `c:\packages`:

```
xcopy.exe /y "$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)Commons.*.nupkg" "c:\packages"
```

If you do not want to change the version, you do not need to do more things in the point.

**2. Re-install the re-packed to the solution:**

After re-pack the nuget package, you need to replace the old nuget package with the new one in the packages source.

**Need to point out** that the command `Update-Package Commons -reinstall` will **NOT** re-install the new version package.

Because when you use this command to re-install nuget package, nuget will check the packages folder if exists that package `Commons.1.0.0.nupkg`, if it exists, **nuget will not restore the nuget package, so nuget will not to re-download the new version package in the package source**. So Nuget still re-install the old package. That is the reason why you got the problem.

To resolve this issue, you need to **delete the package in the packages folder**, then execute the re-install command to re-install the package. Or you can uninstall the package first, then re-install it.

One more things, if you then use a different version of the package, you can use update package directly to install the new version package, not need to pay attention to delete package/uninstall first.

Hope this is clear.

Answer (score 0):

So... after trying 1000 things I was able to figure it out.

The correct **command** is :
`nuget pack Commons.csproj -BasePath .\ -IncludeReferencedProjects`

So missing the basepath was basically all

**Post Build** Event for someone else

`"$(ProjectDir)nuget.exe" pack "$(ProjectDir)Commons.csproj" -BasePath "$(ProjectDir)-IncludeReferencedProjects`

Comment: and weirdly it doesnt work from post build , have to run it manually......

Comment: Thanks for sharing your helpful information here, if possible, you could mark it as the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issue as yours. Have a nice day.